# Andengine weird texture issue

Tags: android, textures, andengine

I'm trying to develop a game using Andengine. It's been a while since I last worked with andengine, so I downloaded the latest andengine.jar. 
The **Texture** class changed to **BitmapTextureAtlas**
So I used BitmapTextureAtlas instead of texture. Everything was fine except the quality of textures are changed. While using Texture its fine but using BitmapTextureAtlas, its has some weird pixel like border which appears different on every start. Sometimes more or less

Heres the link to the image of how the texture looks:

[image]

I've tried different things but it doesnt go. This problem wasn't seen when i was using **Texture**
I hope anybody has an idea how this can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the current AndEngine version has a `.jar` file in the internet. It might be an older version.

Try cloning AndEngine on your own, so you will have the most updated version.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't the current version but the one downloaded from the andengine forum. And I found the answer to my problem. I had to make my images to the power of two. It solved those weird lines. Thanks anyways.

Comment: On the current version of AndEngine, Nicholas added javadoc for the constructor of `BitmapTextureAtlas` with a note that the width and height have to be a power of 2.